# Rails 2.3.14 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have an existing app that runs on Rails 2.3.14. I'm setting up my environment with RVM to use Ruby 1.8.7-p374, and I installed Rails 2.3.14, and it seems as if my install isn't working.

I'm trying to verify my install of Rails by running `rails -v`, however running that command yields this:

```
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `setup': undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x104f28960> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `map'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `each'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `map'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `setup'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:114:in `check'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:121
from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `run'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@leaselabs/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10
```

Comment: what is the output of `gem list` and `rvm list`

Comment: Check here for my output of those commands: http://snipt.org/Bazc3

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of the commands to the question. Don't expect potential answerers to chase down the information you've been asked to supply; Remember, they're volunteers trying to help a lot of people, not just you, so the less "chasing" they have to do the better. Also, *WHEN* link-rot sets in your added information won't be available, and will make your question mostly useless.

Comment: looks like a bug in `rubygems-bundler`, please open an issue here https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/issues

Answer (score 1):

I have resovled this.
method:rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler.