# Any rails command gives noexec.rb:75:in `setup': undefined method `name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, bcrypt

First time question here forgive me if I am not descriptive. Running Ruby 1.8.7 w/ rails 2.3.5 If I run any rails or rake task I get

```
/home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `setup': undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x7f45a2fe73a8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `map'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `map'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `setup'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:114:in `check'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:121
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `run'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.6/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /home/mathew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@wholesale/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10
```

my gem list is:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
atomic (1.1.14)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
daemons (1.0.10)
delayed_job (2.0.4)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
hpricot (0.8.4)
i18n (0.6.5, 0.5.0)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.2)
mysql (2.8.1)
nokogiri (1.4.1)
rack (1.5.2, 1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.0.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rubygems-update (2.1.10, 1.8.25)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
```

From what I have read bcrypt-ruby and bundler don't play nice together. So I tried to uninstall bundler and rubygems-bundler (because rubygems-bundler is in the error output) but they don't seem to be uninstalled when I run gem list :/ Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Seems duplicated with: [Rails 2.3.14 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803942/rails-2-3-14-not-working) and the answer there was: Remove bundle from global gemset

```
$ rvm @global
$ gem uninstall bundler
```

Comment: It was a combination of that and using the right rubygems version. Thank you!

Comment: I've also seen that `rubygems-bundler` can cause the same issue as the OP. In fact, looking at the stack trace from the question, it looks like rubygems-bundler was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For those coming from a search engine: In my case, with rubygems 3.1.1 and bundler 2.1.0, the issue was still having rubygems-bundler installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@timing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
    5: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    4: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    3: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    2: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems-bundler/noexec (LoadError)
    10: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@timing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
     8: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
     7: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
     6: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
     4: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'
     2: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84:in `setup': undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration:0x00007f90bf0cb3e8> (NoMethodError)
```

Looking into the situation, [the readme](https://github.com/rvm/rubygems-bundler) has this to say:

> Generally, this gem is not needed on RubyGems >= 2.2.0.

The solution was to remove that gem from the `@global` gemset:

```
rvm @global
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler
```